# Signalr connection forcefully close when sending request to aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, signalr, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

- At beginning of project I use http for connecting with ec2 directly with ip address not domain name and its connects fine and worked fine to my c# client and web client that connected to ec2 through ip adderess.
- Recently I added Https to my load balancer and configured all ec2 with https security groups and there trouble started.
- Signalr web client with https and ip address connects fine on ec2 but c# client with https and ip address not connecting. C# client throw connection close method continuously.
- To solve that I change my connection url from ip to elastic beanstalk domain name to c# client and signalr connected but following things happen.

1) First time when I connect with beanstalk domain name, it response with 400 header error on connection establishment and serve also reply data from database so first time connection established.

2) After server's reply I invoke another method of server at that time error occurred stated that connection disconnected please start connection before making request to server.

3) In signalr there is a connection close method that invoke if connection has been close and it is not invoking.

4) I have searched my query in Internet and found that we have to configured socket connection on beanstalk as they have same issue with nginx. I am using IIS and there is no particular answer for that.

5) I have try to connect directly on ec2 instance domain name but signalr did not established connection and directly fire connection close method without any error or warning.

6) In my network configuration I have enabled inbound port with 443 and 80. If i made request from my browser to that domain url of beanstalk or ec2 its works fine

- If you have any idea to configure socket on aws ec2 or elastic beanstalk might help to solve this problem.